# Open .NET implementation of the OGC Geometry Object Model from Simple Feature Access 1 specification?

Tags: .net, ogc, geometry

I am looking for a .NET implementation of the geometry object model described in *[OGS's Simple Feature Access, Part 1](http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/sfa)* specification.

Preferably lightweight. I don't need WKT support, just the capability of instantiating spatially referenced geometries and the ability to determine basic spatial relationships between them.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check [Net Topology Suite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nts/) with  [GeoAPI .NET](http://geoapi.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 4):

+1 for the NTS & GeoAPI.

You could also use the SqlGeometry in Microsoft.SqlServer.Types:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeometry_members.aspx

If you scroll to the bottom of this page, there is an c# example of constructing geometry and calling an OGC method:
http://www.microsoftbible.com/tag/sqlgeometry

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I hesitate to commit myself to types from the Microsoft.SqlServer namespace (Mono ambitions later on), but +1 as this may be less of a concern for others.

Answer (score 3):

I've also had luck using the actual [Java Topology Suite](http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/main.html) (JTS) on which many open-source 2D geometry libraries are based. Using the scarily amazing [IKVM](http://www.ikvm.net/), you can just compile JTS as a .NET Assembly and you're off and away. You can use the objects natively, or you can wrapper them if you feel like it. The raw JTS library is rather light on input/output options, but computationally you're all set.